# A warning pops up when I run my code. I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python, pygame

So, the code I wrote is working just fine but a warning keeps popping up. I don't know what it means and what to do with it. The warning is below:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/GROOT!/ch.py", line 41
    win.blit(char, (x, y))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
```

I don't know if I need to change something in my code or not. Please tell me what I need to do.

Comment: `int(x), int(y)` and see `print(x,y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you mute this warning using

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=Warning)
```

or you convert x and y to int using `int(x), int(y)`

Comment: Thanks both @xzelda and @furas! Both your answers work

Comment: You should not recommend filtering the warning as an option (particularly since the fix is so straightforward). If they do that the code may just break at some later point because, as the error says "Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python."

Answer (score 1):

Warning means that `x` and/or `y` have float values but `blit()` (and other functions in PyGame) needs integer values. You can use `int(x), int(y)` to change it

```
win.blit(char, (int(x), int(y)))
```

Warning informs also that this time it converts it automatically to integer but in next PyGame's version it may not do this and it is better to use `int()` manually.